# Pose data from one armature to another

Tags: armature

I have two very similar armatures, one has 2 extra bones, but otherwise they match exactly. I need to copy the pose from one to the another. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: if common bones have identical names, and hierarchy, it could work using the 3dview buttons (shortcuts ctrl+c, ctrl+v for copy and paste). It worked to me on a simple test.

Comment: Both armatures are in rest pose so nothing happens. My problem is both rest poses are different and I need them to match. I can do it manually but it's unexact.

Comment: If your rest poses do not match, you cannot just copy the pose data from one to other. You need to constrain one armature bones to copy rotations, locations and scale from the other and then apply the constraints (Pose > Apply Pose as Rest Pose)

Comment: Great, it's going to take me some time to constain everything but so far it worked! Thanks!

Comment: So, assuming the armatures do match, how does one transfer the pose data? Could someone post an answer that works with Blender 2.8+?